# Amchart x-axis date format

Tags: amcharts

I have a amchart with two different categories, i get the date from mysql database in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. My Problemist that the date is not displayed correct on my chart.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var chart;
       var graph;
        var chartData4 = [
{"year":"2014-11-05 21:16:37", "v1":7.3, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 21:17:36", "v1":7.3, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 21:18:07", "v1":7.3, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 21:30:01", "v1":7.3, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 21:45:02", "v1":7.2, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 22:00:01", "v1":7.2, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 22:15:01", "v1":7.1, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 22:30:02", "v1":7.1, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 22:45:02", "v1":7.1, "v2":99.9},
            {"year":"2014-11-05 23:00:02", "v1":7.1, "v2":99.9},
        ......

            {"year":"2014-11-07 19:45:02", "v1":5.5, "v2":96.3},
            {"year":"2014-11-07 20:00:02", "v1":5.5, "v2":96.3},
            {"year":"2014-11-07 20:15:02", "v1":5.5, "v2":97.1},
                            {"year":"2014-11-07 20:30:02", "v1":5.5, "v2":96.9}
        ];

   AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIAL CHART
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.pathToImages = "http://allopensensors.com/amcharts/images/";
            chart.dataProvider = chartData4;
            chart.marginLeft = 10;
            chart.categoryField = "year";
            chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS";
            chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

            // AXES
            // category
            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.parseDates = true;
            categoryAxis.minPeriod = "ss";
            categoryAxis.dashLength = 3;
            categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
            categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.1;

            // value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.id = "ax1";
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.inside = true;
            valueAxis.dashLength = 3;
            valueAxis.position = "right";
     valueAxis.title="Temperature in degree celsius" ;
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            var valueAxis2 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis2.id = "ax2";
            valueAxis2.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis2.inside = true;
            valueAxis2.dashLength = 3;
            valueAxis2.baseValue = -20;
            valueAxis2.position = "left";
  valueAxis2.title="Humidity in %";
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis2);

            // GRAPH
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.label="Temperature";
            graph.valueaxis = "ax1";
            graph.type = "smoothedLine";
            graph.lineColor = "#d16fff";
            graph.negativeLineColor = "#637bb6";
            graph.bullet = "square";
            graph.bulletSize = 8;
            graph.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
            graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
            graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
            graph.lineThickness = 2;
            graph.valueField = "v1";
            graph.title = "title v1";
            graph.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph2.valueAxis = "ax2";
            graph2.type = "smoothedLine";
            graph2.lineColor = "#d1655d";
            graph2.negativeLineColor = "#637bb6";
            graph2.bullet = "round";
            graph2.bulletSize = 8;
            graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
            graph2.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
            graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
            graph2.lineThickness = 2;
            graph2.valueField = "v2";
            graph2.title = "title v2";
            graph2.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]    </span></b>";
 graph2.label="TESSST";
            chart.addGraph(graph2);

            // CURSOR
            var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
            chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0;
            chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
            chartCursor.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "JJ:NN:SS";
            chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

            // SCROLLBAR
            var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
            chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

            chart.creditsPosition = "bottom-right";

            // WRITE

            chart.write("chartdiv4");
        });
</script>
```

See it here: http://allopensensors.com/author/andreas , the third chart,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the other charts you have the line **categoryAxis.parseDates = true;** commented out, on the third chart is isn't.  This will provide you with the axis to match the others.

As you have time data then the charts do look better in my opinion with the axis as they are in chart 3.  I would personally remove the comment from the other charts to match this one.